# Handling back button (Android)

Tags: android, back-button

I have an application which requires the user to log in to see the content. When the user pushes the back button, he is given a prompt if he wants to log out, or stay on the application. However, I want to make it so that if the user presses the back button again, the application sends him back to the log out screen. How can I do this?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    exitPrompt();

}
private void exitUser(){
    UserFunctions userFunk = new UserFunctions();   
    userFunk.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
    userFunk.resetCarcoord(getApplicationContext());
    Intent logout = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(logout);
    finish();

}
private void exitPrompt(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle("Log out")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            exitUser();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class with a Boolean variable mIsexitPromptShowing and AlertDialog instance, when  exitPrompt() is called; make mIsexitPromptShowing instance as true and store AlertDialog instance.

On onBackPressed() function:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

   if (!mIsexitPromptShowing) {
      exitPrompt();
   } else {
      AlertDialog.dismiss();
   }

}
```

I have just given a sample code, please do handle the safe check.
Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the first click on the back button, start a timer. (a CountDownTimer for example)
Then, if the user clicks again on the back button, cancel the timer and redirect him to the logout screen.
If, he doesn't, when the timer finishes, show the dialog.

Comment: This works, but I don't like the solution of waiting for the dialog to show, so I'll go with the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlertDialog.setOnCancelListener(...)`. This method is called when the dialog is canceled by the user. Note that this is different from being dismissed - a Dialog can be dismissed in other ways, for instance as part of a configuration change.

```
private void exitPrompt(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        /*...*/
        .setOnCanelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()) {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                exitUser();
            }
        })
        /*...*/
}
```

If you do your dialogs with DialogFragment instead, you can alternatively override the `onCancel()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Overide this method in your activity or in Fragment

```
    @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if(condition) {
        //Write your code with this condition
    }
    else {  
        //To finish this activity  
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
```